# Hogging all my internet speed

Tags: networking, internet

when I turn my xbox one, it automatically starts downloading. While doing that process, the xbox one takes all the internet, and other device cannot use internet properly. It gets extremely slow. I'm wondering on how to do that on PC.

Comment: You want to do what exactly on Ubuntu?

Comment: So basically, I want to take all of our INTERNET connection like my xbox one. I want to suck up all the internet connection and only use it for my pc.

Comment: This sounds more like a QoS (Quality of Service) question that would deal more with your router and not your Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I DEAL with it then?

Comment: You configure the QoS priorities of your devices in your router.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to allow your laptop to use all the bandwidth (data) on your network via the laptop. All of that is managed by your router.

If you have a fairly decent router, you may be able to find something called "QoS" which stands for *Quality of Service*. QoS will allow you to select a device on your network, and then the router will automatically make sure that the device you selected will get the best performance. But there is a tradeoff. All of the other devices on the network **will** lose speed. This is because your laptop will now be taking priority over everyone else's.

Something else I would like to mention is that it sounds quite strange for an Xbox to hog all the bandwidth on your network. Usually it will only do that if it is downloading an update, or updating a game. A quick remedy for this would be to turn on the xbox late at night when no one is on the network, and allow it to do it's thing. As long as the files aren't too large, it shold be done by morning and should no longer use up all your bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, it does when it's downloading update or downloading a game. I'm asking you that how xbox one did it without a help by me who can change the QOS. I didn't gave xbox one a priority but it automatically gets the speed. I'm asking you if it's possible to do that on my pc without changing QOS, and make it stable.

Comment: Your xbox is probably not getting the speed automatically. However some routers are smart enough to know what kind of device is connected. So it is actually really likely that your router determined that the xbox needs a high speed internet connection so you can play games with no lag, so therefore, it may be automatically giving the xbox all the bandwidth.

Comment: I've never knew that my router is that smart....

Comment: BUT keep in mind that ANY device on the network using data will slow down all the others. Imagine you are driving on a 5-lane highway, and there are only two cars on it. That means you can drive fast right? But now imagine there are 5,000 cars on the same stretch. Near standstill traffic. Thats what it is like when your xbox is downloading, it is putting 5,000 cars on the road before you get a chance to put on 2. Make sense?

Comment: #BestAnswerEver. I know can understand it better. So you are saying that internet has a same system as a traffic? So basically if there is a more people who is connected to a internet, the less internet speed is given for people. But I don't get why xbox one is the ONLY one who is getting the higher speed and others are getting LOW speed. With using your car example, why is xbox one is taking shortcut? or "different" than other cars?

Comment: Haha, funny how this example works out because the technical term for data on a network is usually called "traffic" But just think the highway as having dozens of on-ramps in a 1-mile stretch. The xbox is trying to add as many cars as it can to use up all the available lanes using these on-ramps. The cars are not special in any way, but there are a lot of them trying to get on the road, so everyone else has to kinda scootch out of the way. QoS is like the police. QoS will tell the xbox to stop putting so many cars on, and it will also make sure that the 2 cars you have will have room to go

Comment: Wait, so if my understanding is right, does that mean that the xbox the car is either GIANT or seperated with few other cars? then... cant my pc can do the same?

Comment: Sort of. The main problem here is that no matter what EVERYONE gets slowed down. So if you used your laptop, then the Xbox would get slowed as well. The biggest difference here is that the Xbox doesn't care. It will just continue moving at whatever speed it can. You on the other hand, want your videos to load fast. Overall, you are doing the same thing to the Xbox, it's just that since there's no QoS, there's no traffic control